# How to detach screen programmatically in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

This question is about the linux utility screen.

I'd like to make a script to launch a program in screen then detatch it automatically after it starts.

I've got the script starting screen, starting the command in screen, but my question is now how do I detach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't attach in the first place. From the screen manual:

```
  -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
          doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
          scripts.
```

Comment: would i say something like: screen -d -m /home/user1/script.sh ??

Comment: -dmS name commands to run works fine and ensures your screen session has a name so its easier to find